# inserting an element in an xml document using its xpath

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Here is the issue, I have an incomplete document (docA) and would like to insert some xml element at some specific position defined by some xpath string (in a doc elementList) to get a complete document (docB).

So basically, given the document docA:

```
<document>
    <information type="person">
        <id>string</id>
        <customer>
            <customerID>abc</customerID>
            <externalID>2</externalID>
            <person>
                <gender>M</gender>
                <firstName>John</firstName>
                <!-- here should be a middle name -->
                <lastName>Doe</lastName>
                <birthdate>2011-05-05</birthdate>
            </person>
            <!-- more elements... -->
        </customer>
        <!-- more elements... -->
    </information >
</document>
```

and the elementList:

```
<newElementSet>
   <element>
      <name>Middle Name</name>
      <path>/document/information/customer/person/middleName</path>
      <value>Fitzgerald</value>
   </element>
   <!-- some more element could go there -->
</newElementSet>
```

the output document should be:

```
<document>
    <information type="private">
        <id>string</id>
        <customer>
            <customerID>abc</customerID>
            <externalID>2</externalID>
            <person>
                <gender>M</gender>
                <firstName>John</firstName>
                <middleName>Fitzgerald</middleName>
                <lastName>Doe</lastName>
                <birthdate>2011-05-05</birthdate>
            </person>
                <!-- more elements... -->
        </customer>
        <!-- more elements... -->
    </information >
</document>
```

Any way this could be done in xslt? I tried using Xquery but it doesn't seem to be possible (cannot use the Xquery update as it's not yet supported).

Edit: I just want to precise that this is just a simplified presentation of the problem. In reality, we have more element to add and there values are actually going to be taken from user inputs...

Comment: Your XPath does not tell where in the `<person>` element your new element should go. Does it matter?

Comment: In some case, it actually might, this is defined in our schema. Does it means we have to modify our xpath definition or add some more information?

Comment: Provided `<element/>` description doesn't contain any unique information to identify which `customer/person` you needs to update. Or you want add '<middleName>Fitzgerald</middleName>` to all persons?

Comment: there should be only one person so the adding can be done on "all" I think. But this raises an interesting question, I need to look. 
But for the simple case I think we can consider it to be unique.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a 16-line short and easy solution.

Answer (score 1):

**This can be done very easily, you only have to change the "elementList" document a little bit -- to this XML document**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="person/firstName">
  <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
  <middleName>Fitzgerald</middleName>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Then just apply this transformation to the provided source XML document**:

```
<document>
    <information type="person">
        <id>string</id>
        <customer>
            <customerID>abc</customerID>
            <externalID>2</externalID>
            <person>
                <gender>M</gender>
                <firstName>John</firstName>
                <!-- here should be a middle name -->
                <lastName>Doe</lastName>
                <birthdate>2011-05-05</birthdate>
            </person>
            <!-- more elements... -->
        </customer>
        <!-- more elements... -->
    </information >
</document>
```

**and the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<document>
   <information type="person">
      <id>string</id>
      <customer>
         <customerID>abc</customerID>
         <externalID>2</externalID>
         <person>
            <gender>M</gender>
            <firstName>John</firstName>
            <middleName>Fitzgerald</middleName><!-- here should be a middle name -->
            <lastName>Doe</lastName>
            <birthdate>2011-05-05</birthdate>
         </person><!-- more elements... -->
      </customer><!-- more elements... -->
   </information>
</document>
```

**Discussion**:

1. This solution is surprizingly simpler than trying to implement any kind of dynamic evaluation.
2. The XML document specifying the wanted changes is compact.
3. The logic is straight and not convoluted as with any partial dynamic evaluation implementation.
4. No additional XSLT document is necessary.
5. This is a simple and easy to implement, understand and maintain solution.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the idea,the issue here is that I need somehow to be able to handle more parameters and more paths... but maybe adding a first step and modifying the path/value definition would allow to get the best of both world

Comment: @florent: The idea is that writing a small and easy transformation that makes the modifications is much easier and straightforward than putting a large effort to implement an incomplete and error-prone partial XPath-expression dynamic evaluation that is not guaranteed "the next time", needs additional changes every "next time" and gradually becomes unmaintainable monster. Compare this monster to the tiny stylesheet (also an XML document by itself) and decide which approach is better :)

Comment: I understand, and I'm looking for a simple and clean solution (I know the risk of monstrosity) But I have also this specific constraint. I also want to precise that this is not meant to be a one shot transformation but a repeated one. Values are coming from user input so we need a minimum of "dynamic" evaluation. I'm also trying to find the correct limit between what should be dynamic and what should be fixed (YAGNI and all) :)